# Vite and React Issue: 'text/jsx' MIME Type Error with ReactDOM.createRoot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I'm encountering an issue while using Vite and React in my project. Specifically, I'm getting a MIME type error ('text/jsx') when trying to render my application using ReactDOM.createRoot. This issue is impacting the proper execution of my React application.

I've followed all the procedures, but my page isn't displaying. Even tutorials are not working. I need help with this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.